# A user keeps criticizing all my answers - some taughts about downvotes

Tags: discussion, support

I usually do my best to be kind to people and describe all my ideas and possible solutions to their problems.

At some point (I don't know when/how) I might have insulted someone, or at least I probably made him angry somehow, because for a time, I'm having a feeling that he keeps tracking my answers, and as soon as he sees one, no matter if it is useful answer or not, he downvotes it and starts to criticize with untrue arguments.

for example there is a question like:
"how to eat soup?"

as an answer I write:
"if possible do it with a spoon, but if you don't have one, try drinking it and give a feedback."

short after, this person appears, instantly downvotes my answer and comments that this is such a bad idea and how bad idea it is to "drink it".
I even saw him comment on other answers that "this is a much better idea than drinking" - (always the same person)

(sorry for my bad metaphor, best that came in my mind right now)

Even though I flag his comments and usually they are removed, it is not only weird but also annoying in a long term.

So what should I do to get rid of him, or make him stop?
Already tried reasoning with him but I had no luck.

---

Edit:
To sum up things, downvotes most of the cases can be quite demoralizing, when You do the research, take the effort to try to help others, and some brusque user comes and because he had a bad day or he is just like this in life, takes the joy of helping away.

My suggestion is, that this should be modified, in order to downvote someone, users should be forced to leave a comment as a reason or at least some sort of feedback for the user. I do not say that their name should appear, I just want a reason...

Comment: Examples would be helpful

Comment: @Ramhound - You do misunderstand me again. Just for once, please read my post with a bit more attention. Where did I write, I want the downvotes to be non anonymous? Let me quote myself: `My suggestion is, that this should be modified, in order to downvote someone, users should be forced to leave a comment as a reason or at least some sort of feedback for the user. I do not say that their name should appear, I just want a reason...`

Comment: @Ramhound - what I am trying to say is that the feedback that You provide is not constructive, and rude.

Comment: @Ramhound - I am saying that a pop up windows could be implemented to the site where the downvoting person has to write his reasons. The user could see the reason, not the person downvoting.

Comment: @Ramhound - I did not thought it over 100%, I was just sort of "brainstorming". However I mentioned that: `I do not say that the downvoting users name should appear`
Maybe you are right, but at least it helps the person to understand what he did wrong, so next time he will not.

Answer (score 7):

Some users are more brusque than others. I looked through some of your downvoted answers, and while some of the comments other users left were not very nicely worded, I can't disagree with the general idea of what they're getting at. Many of your answers come off as unsure – you say "I'm not really sure" and "I don't know exactly what you're asking but try this" a lot. It's OK to be unsure about what a question is asking, but your answers may be better received if you word them to ask clarifying questions while still being confident. For example, if you're unsure about what a user is asking, but know the answer for one possible interpretation of their question, you could say "I am unclear about *foo* in your question, but if you mean *bar* then the solution would be *baz*." instead of "I don't know for sure but maybe try *baz*." It says the same thing, but it sounds more confident and allows room for the question asker to provide clarification.

I did look at your profile and can see that a particular user has downvoted you enough times to show up in our voting irregularity detection systems. This particular user has a very high ratio of downvotes to upvotes; in other words, he is quite critical to many people – not just you. Other people have also felt like his comments are rather brusque and could be considered rude by some. Please understand that this isn't personal. Some people's personalities are easier to get along with than others.

I see that you have gotten quite a few upvotes in a short amount of time, so keep up the good work, continue working to make your answers the best they can be, take constructive criticism into account, and don't let grumpy people on the internet get you down.

Comment: Thank You for the good words, I believe most problems can be solved by trying out things. I usually give a possible solution, than wait for feedback, if the solution does not seat the authors needs, I update my answer. So this means I can do nothing about this user, just ignore him and try to remain positive, like smc wrote.

Comment: @Ramhound - It might be helpful if You would even try to understand my point before blaming it. Compare your way of writing with nhinkle's. As You can see, his words are constructive and still nice. Yours are just rude and negative. Lets not forget that we are humans.

Comment: @Ramhound - apology accepted. In the future, just try to be a bit nicer. Giving the respect to another human is never a bad thing.

Answer (score 3):

Just live with it. There are plenty of weirdos in this world. You should not be wasting your time and energy on each and every one.

- **To get rid of him** - ignore him for a while he, will get bored and go away
- **To save yourself some stress** - stop reading or flagging his comments
- **To get some good karma** - go answer some questions and upvote some good answers
- **To be be happy** - don't eat soap

Peace

smc

Comment: @Ramhound - That will solve nothing. Don't be so drastic about this. All I want You to do is to be nice and reasonable. Since You started commenting here, I realized that You are able to be nice. You should be always like this... Look, if You have something against someone, no one will judge You for being honest with him. For example if you see my answer is bad, You can say that "hey, you could improve your answer by [this]..." and You can also say "your answer just sucks". The first one will encourage me to improve my answer. The second one will just make me feel bad and demotivate me.

Comment: *"don't eat soap"* - words worth living by (and the rest too!)